# Reading csv from multiple subfolders - elegant solution

Tags: r, dplyr

I read csv files from subfolders (marked as year) as follows:

```
All <- lapply(c(2021,2022,2023,2024), function (subfolder) {
  PV.Moc_flist <- dir_ls(paste0(sciezka, "PV/", subfolder, "/"), regexp = paste0("[0-9](*)" ,"-(.*)csv$"))
  All.act <- lapply(PV.Moc_flist,function(i){
    read.csv(i,  header=TRUE, sep=",", dec = ".", na.strings = "***", skipNul = TRUE)
  })
  All.act <- do.call (plyr::rbind.fill, All.act) %>% 
    mutate (DT = as.POSIXct(Time, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))   
  }
  )

PV.Moc_multi <- do.call (plyr::rbind.fill, All)
```

It works, but the nesting of lapply inside lapply suggests that a more elegant solution is possible. If so, please give me some tips.

Comment: What package is `dir_ls` from and what does it do? Is your desired final result a single data frame with all files combined?

Comment: @jpsmith From ```fs``` package. dir_ls() is equivalent to the ls command. It returns filenames as a named fs_path character vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made three folders ("2020", "2021", and "2022") in an example folder titled "Example" that all contains an example file "test_2020", “test_2021”, etc that looks like this:

```
# A B   C
# 1 2   3
# 4 5   6
# 7 8   9
```

If you goal is to find all the files in the relevant subfolders ending in "[number].csv" and `rbind` them together, you can use the following base R approach:

```
flpth <- list.files("~[insert_filepath]/Example", full.names = TRUE)

do.call(rbind,
        lapply(flpth, \(x) read.csv(list.files(x, pattern = "[0-9](*).csv", full.names = TRUE)))
)
```

Output

```
#   A B C
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 4 5 6
# 3 7 8 9
# 4 1 2 3
# 5 4 5 6
# 6 7 8 9
# 7 1 2 3
# 8 4 5 6
# 9 7 8 9
```

Or since you tagged `dplyr`, here is an analogous tidyverse-alterative approach (using `purrr::map()`:

```
flpth %>% 
  purrr::map(~list.files(.x, pattern = "[0-9]*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>%
               purrr::map_df(read.csv)) %>%
  bind_rows()

#   A B C
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 4 5 6
# 3 7 8 9
# 4 1 2 3
# 5 4 5 6
# 6 7 8 9
# 7 1 2 3
# 8 4 5 6
# 9 7 8 9
```

Comment: ```regexp = paste0("[0-9](*)" ,"-(.*)csv$")``` is supposed to allow reading all csv files starting with a digit (01-01.csv,02-01.csv, .. ., 31-01.csv, 01-02.csv, ..., 29-02.csv).

Comment: change the `pattern = ` to whatever fits your data

Comment: @GrBa You don't need `paste0`, simply `regexp = "[0-9](*)-(.*)csv$"` is equivalent.